# Is it possible to add an article after the preposition "next to"?

Tags: prepositions

Is it possible to add an article after the preposition "next to" (in case that I want to specify a noun)  or it's idiom which includes already definite article such as the idiom "at home")?

For example: 
"The rice is in the kitchen, in the cupboard next to (**the**?) sink."

Comment: Yes, in fact it is more or less mandatory. Such as *I sat next to the window*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use something which specifies the *location* for

> **next to**

And it is the same general rule using "***the***" and "***a***".

> I sat next to **a** window.
>   *I sat next to any window*
>
> I sat next to **the** window.
>   *I sat next to a specific window*

But it does not need to be an *article*

> I sat next to **my** girlfriend.